# Fading in a background image using javascript or css on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, fade

So far, i've been able to make it such that when the cursor hovers over the div a background image in the body appears. I need to add a fade in animation to this. Ive been looking for solutions here but havent been able to work around it. I don't have any experience in javascript.

```
enter code here
<script>


    changeBgImage = () => {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../Images/Background/wraithback.jpg')";
        console.log("working")




    }
    ogBgImage = () => {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../Images/Background/black.jpg')";
        console.log("working")
    }


</script>

<style>
    body {
        background-image: url('../Images/Background/black.jpg');
    }
</style>
<body>
<div class="gwraith"><a href="../Legends/wraith.html ">
                    <img src="../Images/Legends_pics/wraithchibi.png" width="130vw" class="wraith"
                        onmouseover="changeBgImage();" onmouseout="ogBgImage();">
                </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a transition rule to the `body` tag. The same can be done in css, without javascript.

```js
function changeBgImage() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/284/Summer_Pond_Fence_Trees_496376.jpg')";
}

function ogBgImage() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://pristor.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/leto12.jpg')";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://pristor.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/leto12.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  
  transition: all 0.7s linear;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="gwraith">
    <a href="../Legends/wraith.html">
    <img src="https://begin-english.ru/img/word/refresh.jpg" width="130vw" class="wraith"
                            onmouseover="changeBgImage();" onmouseout="ogBgImage();">
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I guess, the author doesn't want to change the background image. Is it possible to set background-image to 'none' smoothly?

Comment: Yes, with the rule of opacity

Comment: If the body has opacity: 0, it will hide everything inside, won't it?

Comment: Of course, therefore, it is better to do this inside (child) the tags.

Comment: But your solution will work if we use blank image as the second background. A little bit tricky, but it solves the issue. I created the stackblitz based on your example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qft2xj?file=index.js But it seems to work in Chrome only.

Comment: this is exactly what i needed, thank you for your answer
here is a video of how it looks:
https://streamable.com/5nxyz7

Comment: this videoservice (`streamable`) is blocked in russia, therefore, I cannot follow the link

Answer (score 1):

I didn't manage to do it with body. But you can stretch the underlying div and change its opacity.

```js
const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");

appDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", showBodyBackground);
appDiv.addEventListener("mouseout", hideBodyBackground);

function showBodyBackground() {
  document.getElementById("bg").classList.add("hidden");
}

function hideBodyBackground() {
  document.getElementById("bg").classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

```css
.visible {
  background: url('https://www.bouwendnederland.nl/media/6502/rijnhaven-impressie-602-x-402.jpg');
  transition: opacity 1.5s linear;
  opacity: 1;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

.stretched {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
}

#app {
  width: 100px;
  height:50px;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="stretched visible" id="bg"></div>
    <div id="app">Hover me!</div>
</body>
```

Be aware, that everything will disappear in the element with opacity: 0. It means, your button and other elements you want to keep on the screen shouldn't be children of that div.

Comment: thank you for ur answer, ive found a pretty good solution by sergey kuznetsov. i have also provided a video showing what it looks

Comment: Good to hear. Just in case. if you support not only Chrome, don't forget to check the solution in Firefox and Edge.

Answer (score 1):

We can't just fade body, or indeed any wrapper div which may replace it, as that would fade everything.  We also can't directly fade a background image as CSS doesn't have that ability. But we can put the two background images into the two pseudo elements, before and after, of body and these can then be animated to fade in and out. The code wants to fade in one background on mouseover, and fade it out on mouseout.

There are two background images used, one called black. The code here fades that out as the other image fades in, but that can be easily removed if required.

Mouse over the gear image to fade in the second image, and mouseout of the gear to fade it out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>


    changeBgImage = () => {
        <!--document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../Images/Background/wraithback.jpg')";-->
        document.body.classList.toggle('showbefore');
        document.body.classList.toggle('showafter');
        console.log("working")




    }
    ogBgImage = () => {
        <!--document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('christmas card 2020 front.jpg')";-->
        document.body.classList.toggle('showbefore');        
        document.body.classList.toggle('showafter');
        console.log("working")
    }


</script>

<style>
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh; /* I added this just to cover the whole window you may not want it */
}



body:before, body:after {
    opacity: 0;
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background-size:cover; /* I added this just to get the background over the whole window - you may or may not want it */
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    animation-duration: 2s; /* change to what you want it to be */
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

body:before {
    background-image: linear-gradient(black, black); /*change this to url('your background image');*/
    animation-name: shown;
}

body:after {
    background-image: url('https://ahweb.org.uk/christmas card 2020 front.jpg');
    animation-name: unshown;
}

body.showbefore:before, body.showafter:after {
    animation-name: show;
}

body.showafter:before, body.showbefore:after {
    animation-name: unshow;
} 
  

@keyframes unshown {
  from {
      opacity: 0;
      }
  to {
      opacity: 0;
      }
  }

@keyframes shown {
  from {
      opacity: 1;
      }
  to {
      opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes unshow {
  from {
      opacity: 1;
      }
  to {
      opacity: 0;
      }
  }

@keyframes show {
  from {
      opacity: 0;
      }
  to {
      opacity: 1;
  }
}

</style>
</head>
<body class="showbefore">
<div class="gwraith"><!--<a href="../Legends/wraith.html ">-->
                    <!--<img src="../Images/Legends_pics/wraithchibi.png" width="130vw" class="wraith"
                        onmouseover="changeBgImage();" onmouseout="ogBgImage();">-->
                        <img src="https://ahweb.org.uk/gear.jpg" width="130vw" class="wraith"
                        onmouseover="event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();changeBgImage();" onmouseout="event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();ogBgImage();">
                <!--</a>-->
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks great! I vote for this answer. The advantage of this approach is that it doesn't change the HTML and we don't need to 'fight' side effects like scrolls caused by an extra div in my answer.

Comment: Glad it worked - thanks, cheers one up to know something worked!

Comment: Hey
I tried doing your code and it kinda works, right now when I hover over the link the background image appears and then fades to black. what i want is for the image to fade in when i hover my mouse over the link

Ive added a video for better understanding
https://streamable.com/is093j

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification, so you want the background img (called black)to remain (not fading at all) and the other image to fade in and out? I'll take a look.

Comment: well, the "black.jpg" is allowed to be removed because the image that fades in already has a black background. so after i take my cursor off of the link "black.jpg" should come back in.
sergey kuznetsov below provided a pretty neat solution, ive provided a link to a video over there as well.
i havent selected a final answer yet as im waiting to see if i get a better solution